# Intellij started displaying files in a weird way?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, bukkit

My Intellij has randomly started to just not display my classes in the correct way for some reason. It was working perfectly fine just a few hours ago, and all of the sudden it doesn't work anymore. All of my Bukkit methods are throwing errors even when I import spigot, and the autocomplete feature isn't working properly. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Do you still see all the required jar dependencies in the module settings: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies ? Please try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart.

Comment: That doesn't seem like it did anything.

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

This is due to unmet dependencies/inability to resolve the methods you are calling.

Check your imports, dependencies, installed JDKs, jkd used by intellij, and check your dependencies' versions.

If all fails, you can create a new project and move the source files to the new project. That will act as a hard reset of everything. (kinda of a last resort but...yeah)